# Need Functions That Wait Until Cache Can Be Verified

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, promise

I'm aware that the immediate response is going to be to use promises for the following problem. However, I've looked at every example I can and nothing seems to be readable to me. Most is done through HTML examples, which I don't understand. Similar posts here have a plethora of arguments on which syntax is appropriate which furthers the confusion. So, please show me how I might use a promise to do the following or if another solution is better.

I'd like for a function to check if the cache is available, and if not, it will reinitialize the cache:

```
function valData(){
  if (arrOfNames || arrOfRanges == null){
    initializeGame();
    Logger.log('Game Initialized')
  }
  else {
    Logger.log('Data Available')
  }
};
```

*I'm aware this is likely sloppy, but stay with me*

This function works as intended, as does the following:

```
function reqVal(valname,x){
  if (x == 0){
    var nameArr = convToString(arrOfNames);
    var valIndex = nameArr.indexOf("" + valname)
    return arrOfRanges[valIndex];
  }
  else {
    var nameArr = convToString(arrOfNames);
    var valIndex = nameArr.indexOf("" + valname)
    return valIndex;
  }
};
```

*Again, very very sloppy but Ill clean things up once I can make them function*

Both of these scripts work fine on their own and return what I need. But if I have a third script:

```
function test(){
  valData();
  var valNum = reqVal('curHP', 0);
  var valIndex = reqVal('curHP',1)
  var newNum = valNum - 5;
  Logger.log(valNum)
  Logger.log(newNum)
  Logger.log(valIndex)
};
```

The `reqVal()` function fails due to the asynchronous nature of GAS and the Cache having expired, but the `valData()` function succeeds and produces the needed array. So, I know I need to add a promise in `valData()` that the `reqVal()` function can read from but have no idea how to format that as examples I've seen have been very unclear.

Comment: I'm not 100 percent sure of what you  are talking about but have you looked [client server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) in the documenation

Comment: 1. Google Apps Script doesn't support Promise object. 2. The question doesn't include enough details. How is reqVal being called? 3. Please add a [mcve] (several functions and variables declarations haven't included, if the aren't required to show the problem, don't include them)

Comment: Can sleep help with your issue?